# Carbon dioxide sequestration in Limestone

Tags: catalysis, geochemistry

The chemical reaction where dissolved carbon dioxide forms carbonic acid and then reacts with various calcium containing minerals to form calcium carbonate and bicarbonate is rather slow. I know that several years ago there was research into possible ways to speed up the reaction, possibly as a candidate for a truly long term way to scrub $\mathrm{CO}_2$ from the atmosphere. The inspiration for this idea is to speed up the part of the [geologic carbon cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_cycle#Geological_carbon_cycle) that regulates atmospheric $\mathrm{CO}_2$ concentration.

Does anyone know how the research into catalysts or processes to speed this up are going?

Comment: This should give you a start on recent developments in the field: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?as_ylo=2016&q=carbon+sequestration&hl=en&as_sdt=0,39

Answer (score 1):

[This process](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/scientists-take-another-step-toward-safely-burying-co2/) does not rely on catalysts, but it addresses the essence of the question. The process described is to inject liquefied carbon dioxide into basalt formations, even if the basalt is very old. This makes the it plausible that we could scrub the excess $\mathrm{CO}_2$ from the atmosphere by:

1. growing plants,
2. burning those plants, capturing the CO2, and
3. burying that carbon using, partly, the energy from the burned plants.

Comment: Yes, but nature has already converted plants to more energy efficient hydrocarbon compounds (oil & gas) via heat and pressure.

Comment: Going via plants seems rather an overelaborate way of getting carbon dioxide. Why not just capture it from the atmosphere chemically? Or, just grow plants and **don't** burn them.

Comment: @matt_black Simple - concentration. This process goes this fast because the carbon dioxide is highly concentrated. Doing that mechanically from the atmosphere requires the input of energy. Doing it from an exhaust flue requires less energy because it's more concentrated.

Comment: @SeanLake You still don't need to grow plants and burn them as we already burn vast quantities of coal, oil and gas and could put the capture sequestration on their exhausts.

Comment: @matt_black Preventing fossil carbon from entering the atmosphere doesn't remove carbon that was dumped there in the past, which is the goal.

Comment: @SeanLake But *avoiding* emissions would have exactly the same effect on the atmosphere as *sequestering* already emitted gas. The only significant difference is economics. Besides, growing plants *already* sequesters carbon dioxide and burning them just wastes extra energy.

Comment: No, it does not. We're already at the point where we want to reduce CO2, and waiting for the natural geologic cycle while we just stop making the situation worse won't cut it. Also, plants don't sequester carbon in a meaningful way, since it's still part of the biologic carbon cycle. There are only two long-term sequestration strategies that I'd trust: CO2 to limestone, and burying charcoal.

Comment: @SeanLake a **net increase** in growing plants will lead to removal of CO2 from the atmosphere. More forests = less CO2. And the major geological route to remove CO2 is weathering of olivine-rich rocks. Injecting CO2 into such rocks has been proposed as a way to speed this process up to reduce atmospheric cO2 meaningfully on human timescales.

Comment: @matt_black "Injecting CO2 into such rocks has been proposed as a way to speed this process up to reduce atmospheric cO2 meaningfully on human timescales." Did you even read the question/answer? That's what I said.
Also, no net increase in plants will be sufficient because atmospheric $\mathrm{CO}_2$ is not the major bottle neck in plant growth.